# OpenERP Error: Display tabs using <notebook>

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I tried to display tabs but i got this error: *invalid XML for View Architecture!*

I write the following code :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="employee_form_view">
    <field name="name">employee.form</field>
    <field name="model">employee</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="employee">
            <group colspan="4" col="3">
                <field name="nom" />
                <field name="poste" />
                <field name="employee_age" />
            </group>
            <notebook>
                <page String="Géneral">
                    <sparator string="Links" colspan="4" />
                    <field name="nom" />
                </page>
                <page String="Others">
                    <field name="poste" />
                    <field name="employee_age" />
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

why i get that error ? and how can I fix that problem?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tag

```
<page String="Géneral">
```

is not correct

Correction  :

```
<page string="Géneral">
```

Maybe the accented char will raise an error so you will have to use the html entity.

Comment: there are other issues such as "sparator" instead of "separator".

Comment: the accented char will not cause problems as long as the xml file is saved encoded in UTF-8 (or has the proper XML header with encoding declaration on the first line)

Comment: Thank you QGerome and Gurney alex for your help ,it works fine because of your remarks.

Comment: Indeed , the accented char doesn't cause any problem.